# QML2 ApplicationWindow Keys handling

Tags: qt, event-handling, window, key, qml

Is there any way to handle key press events in ApplicationWindow of `QtQuick.Controls` component? Documentation of Qt5.3 does not provide any way to do this. Also, it says that `Keys` is only exists in `Item`-objects . When I try to handle key press event it says "**Could not attach Keys property to:  ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_16(0x31ab890)  is not an Item**":

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1


ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 720
    height: 405
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    title: qsTr("test")

    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2

    TextField {
        id: textField
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 277
        height: 27
        placeholderText: qsTr("test...")
    }

    Keys.onEscapePressed: {
        mainWindow.close()

        event.accepted = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: mainWindow
  Item {
    focus: true
    Keys.onEscapePressed: {
      mainWindow.close()
      event.accepted = true;
    }
  TextField {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but I've also tried to create `TextField`. When focus is on the `TextField` your solution not works because it has `focus: false` at this time. Your solution works only in case of nothing in that `ApplicationWindow` that can also take focus. I've edited the question to include this textfield.

Comment: @Victor Polevoy all you controls should be children of Item

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this will help some.
Using a `Shortcut` doesn't require `focus` to be set.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Esc"
        onActivated: mainWindow.close()
        }
    }
}
```