# Passing event.key from childs to parent in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I will try to illustrate my question with a simple example.

I have a main window that looks something like this:

```
Item {
    id: root
    LW { id: leftWindow }
    RW { id: rightWindow }
}
```

`leftWindow` and `rightWindow` are `Window`-components, they look something like:

```
Window {
    id: left
    width: 1280
    height: 320
    visible: true

    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
        focus: true

        Keys.onPressed: {
            if (event.key == Qt.Key_Left) {
                event.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I would like to perform some action when a key is pressed regardless of what window is activated at the moment.
This implies that I should somehow catch all `key.event` and pass them on to the parent for both my windows.
The documentation mentioned that events will automatically be propagated upward to parents until `event.accepted = true` is performed, but I have tried it and nothing was really propagated to the root-element.

How can this be done?

Comment: I just noticed your update by chance, since I already put an answer I have to update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a signal in root Item

```
Item {
    id:root
    signal activated(real value)
    onActivated: console.log("Singal emitted with value: " + value)
    LW { id: leftWindow }
    RW { id: rightWindow }
}
```

and emit that signal in each active window

```
Window {
    id: left
    width: 1280
    height: 320
    visible: true
    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: {
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Left) {
                event.accepted = true;
                onPressed: root.activated(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While to forward the event itself back to root Item, a Keys handler can be implemented in main Item and receive events from Window:

```
Item {
    id: root
    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Left){
            event.accepted = true;
            console.log(event.key)
        }
    }
    LW { id: leftWindow }
    RW { id: rightWindow }
    }
```

and in Window:

```
Window {
...
//    Keys.forwardTo: [root]   // Just forward the event, OR action and forward:
        Keys.onPressed: {
            root.Keys.pressed(event)
        }
...
}
```

**Update**: Based on the **edit** in question;

As per [Keyboard Focus in Qt Quick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html), 
The propagation of events takes place up the `QQuickItem` hierarchy, within an active `QQuickWindow` ... until a `QQuickItem` accepts the key event

> 5. If the root Item is reached, the key event is ignored.

The propagation takes places in an `Item` inherited attributes chain [Difference in QML between Window and Item in parent-children relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527083/difference-in-qml-between-window-and-item-in-parent-children-relationship?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

This implies that `QQuickWindow` does not handle nor propagate the event, also as in this post [QML2 ApplicationWindow Keys handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866710/qml2-applicationwindow-keys-handling)

Thus `Window` as the top parent will ignore the event and not propagate further to `Item`. the solution is to manually forward the event, either completely `Keys.forwardTo: [root]` or action and forward.

Comment: I will test and report